# ignore subdirectories timestamps when syncing from shell

Tags: rsync

i want to write a shell command to sync current directory to backup directory with some requirments. the  command i'm using is:

```
   rsync -ptvHS --progress --delete-after --exclude /backup  $pwd ~/backup
```

i want the directory timestamps to be ignored, eventhough i use  -t to preserve the file timestamps.
Any idea?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [man page](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html):

```
    -t, --times                 preserve modification times
    -O, --omit-dir-times        omit directories from --times
    -J, --omit-link-times       omit symlinks from --times
```

Seems like you need to add `-O` to your command.

This is from rsync 3.1.2; you might find your version is too old.